# Call function of header component in react native navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have the code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Parent',
      headerRight: <HeaderComponent />
   }

   render() { return (<Button onPress={...} />); }
}
```

Along with:

```
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {
   ...

   playAnimationOnce = () => { ... }
}
```

Now what I want to do, is I want to be able to call the `playAnimation` function of the `HeaderComponent` class when I press the `Button` in the `Parent` class (so basically where the `...` is located). How would I go on doing this?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done with state rather than passing around functions.

Comment: How would you go on doing this?

Comment: When you change state it could pass a prop to HeaderComponent that causes a rerender.

Comment: How do I pass a non-static state to HeaderComponent when it gets initialized in a static object? Do you have example code?

Comment: Well what are you doing with navigationOptions?  Currently it's unused

Comment: @Jordan react native navigation uses that variable, I thought it could come in handy if I used it in the class itself instead of in App.js.

Comment: You might be able to use setParams, set an active param, and pass header right like so: `headerRight: <HeaderComponent active={navigation.headerActive} />`

See the following for how to update params:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams

Comment: @Jordan Will the prop get updated and cause a rerender in headerRight? Even if so, How would I call the playAnimation function with the active prop?

Comment: I believe that would cause a rerender, but I haven't looked into the internals of how navigationOptions is used - it might not.
See the link for how to update the prop: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams

Comment: @Jordan It's still very unclear what you are trying to do. Can you give me some example code where you achieve the functionality I asked for?